# pgfplots: Unexpected Behaviour of 'extra y tick labels' When Containing Comma and Dollar Sign

Tags: pgfplots

- I want to add `extra y ticks`.
- I also want to define the `extra tick labels` manually by using `extra y tick labels`.
- For the normal `yticklabels` I can use `yticklabels = {{$25,0$},{$30,0$}}`.
- When I use the same syntax for the `extra y tick labels` the I get an error: `! Extra }, or forgotten $.`.
- It does not happen if I do not use the dollar signs (`$`, e. g. `extra y tick labels = {{27,0}}`).
- In my real use case I need the dollar signs.
- Not important: In my country (Germany) the *decimal separator* is the *comma*.

---

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{myDefaultStyle/.style = 
    {
    width = 160mm,
    height = 90mm,
    axis x line = bottom,
    axis y line = left,
    ylabel = y Label,
    xlabel = x Label,   
    grid = major,
    }}

\begin{document}


% ######### Plot #########
% ########################
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        myDefaultStyle,
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 32,
        ymin = 24.5,
        ymax = 30.1,        
        xtick = {0,10,20,30},  
        %% Works Fine 
        ytick = {25,30},     
        yticklabels = {{$25,0$},{$30,0$}},
        %% Does not Work Fine 
%        extra y ticks={27},
%        extra y tick labels = {{$27,0$}},
    ]
    % Plots     
    \addplot[domain=0:10,red]{x}; 
    %
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The currly braces have to be inside the inline math. So you can use either

```
extra y tick labels = {${27,0}$}
```

or

```
extra y tick labels = {$27{,}0$}
```

I would prefer the second one, because the (unwanted) space after the comma is also removed.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{myDefaultStyle/.style = 
    {
    width = 160mm,
    height = 90mm,
    axis x line = bottom,
    axis y line = left,
    ylabel = y Label,
    xlabel = x Label,
    grid = major,
    }}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        myDefaultStyle,
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 32,
        ymin = 24.5,
        ymax = 30.1,
        xtick = {0,10,20,30},  
        %% Works Fine 
        ytick = {25,30},
        yticklabels = {$25{,}0$,$30{,}0$},
        %% Works too
        extra y ticks={27},
        extra y tick labels = {$27{,}0$},
    ]
    % Plots     
    \addplot[domain=0:10,red]{x}; 
    %
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

---

I do not know what you really want to do. But maybe using `\pgfmathprintnumber` could be also an option:

```
yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,use comma]{\tick}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{myDefaultStyle/.style = 
    {
    width = 160mm,
    height = 90mm,
    axis x line = bottom,
    axis y line = left,
    ylabel = y Label,
    xlabel = x Label,
    grid = major,
    }}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        myDefaultStyle,
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 32,
        ymin = 24.5,
        ymax = 30.1,
        xtick = {0,10,20,30},
        yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,use comma]{\tick}},
        ytick = {25,30},
        extra y ticks={27}
    ]
    % Plots     
    \addplot[domain=0:10,red]{x}; 
    %
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: But isn't it strange that the normal tick label behave differently from the extra tick label?

Comment: Use `ytick={25}` and `\yticklabels={{$25,0$}}` and you will get the same error. If there is no list inside the outer currly braces the inner one are ignored.